# Escribir en el teclado en android con el API

Tags: java, android

Buenas estoy desarrollando una aplicación que necesita escribir en cuadros de texto de otra aplicación, me gustaría saber como se podría escribir en un cuadro de texto con código.

Comment: No me queda muy claro a que te refieres con "escribir en cuadros de texto de otra aplicación". Quieres desarrollar un teclado alternativo? Y como quieres modificar el teclado que solicita la otra aplicación?

Comment: @StefanNolde no quiero desarrollar un teclado alternativo, quiero hacer lo mismo que hace la función Robot de Java en PC. Ejemplo:                                                          ´Robot teclado=new Robot();
teclado.keyPress(KeyEvent.TECLA);´

Comment: @StefanNolde Es decir, simular que el usuario escribe cierto texto.

Comment: Si el uso es para tests, podrías revisar `TouchUtils` [API en ingles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html)

Comment: Te dejé una respuesta como puedes simular eventos táctiles si puedes acceder a la actividad o vista que lo debe recibir, no estoy seguro si eso te sirve, porque mencionaste algo de "otra aplicación", en que caso el problema se pone mucho más difícil (si no imposible), porque vas a tener que acceder directamente los métodos de otra app fuera de tu propio paquete. Quizás podrías aclarar tu pregunta en este contexto.

Comment: @StefanNolde Alguna opción alternativa? Por ejemplo usar alguna función de Accesibilidad, para la cual el usuario tendría que autorizar a la aplicación?

Comment: No sé si reflexión te lleva a alguna parte, dependiente de lo que tratas hacer, en todo caso te tengo que avisar que reflexión en dalvik tiene sus usos, pero es asquerosamente lento.

Answer (score 1):

Fuera de tests, puedes crear un `MotionEvent` y usar `dispatchTouchEvent` si conoces y puedes acceder la `Activity` o `View`.

```
MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, metaState);
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent);
```

Los parametros son:

- downTime : el momento en ms cuando el "usuario" tocó la pantalla empezando un flujo de eventos
- eventTime : el momento en ms cuando se generó el evento
- action : en este caso MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, puedes remplazarlo
- x : posición x donde el "usuario" tocó
- y : posición y donde el "usuario" tocó
- metaState : modificadores al evento (como shift, ctrl etc.)

los momentos se obtienen basados en `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`.

Para obtener ejemplos de estos eventos podrías hacer un @Override en una vista o actividad a `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` (no olvides de llamar `super(e)`).

Comment: Interesante, lo probare, la interfaz es algo dinámica por lo que no creo que siempre sea la misma posición, igual veré.

Comment: Claro, las cálculos vas a tener que hacer, al fin lo que tratas es "emular un usuario", si eso sería fácil el ser humano sería aun más ridículo :D